# Repeating Map in SSRS?

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2012, geospatial, ssrs-2012, sqlgeometry

I have a tablix in which I've inserted a chart that repeats based on the tablix row group.  This effectively displays a separate chart in the report for each row group.  I've scheduled this to run daily and it emails off as a pdf.

I'd like to so the same thing with a map but continue to run in to performance issues both in design and when running on the report server.  In visual studio, it's just painfully slow.  On the server, if I schedule it to run, I get status "Error: Thread was being aborted" after a half hour or so of running.

I'm not sure if the issue is related to my spatial data (a "Top 2" works ok), my use of Bing road maps as a base layer or something else.  The spatial data I'm using is in a SQL Server 2012 table.  Lat/Long data is reported from multiple sensors daily.  I've created a view to aggregate the data by sensor for the previous day and built line geometry field from the lat/long pairs.  The source table has ~115k records and my view returns ~90 records with 5 fields, one field being the geometry field.  The dataset in my report is doing a select * on the view.

I've tried with/without the Bing layer.  I've tried adjusting SimplificationResolution property (which I've not located what the units are to even guess what a reasonable value might be).  I'm not sure what else to try.  I would appreciate thoughts or resources that might get me on track.

Comment: Just a thought... Could you turn the map into a subreport and embed that in the tablix cell. I've done similar things (not with maps) and it works well. As you said it's fine for 2 rows it might just make the queries perform better.

Comment: Thanks for the thought, that worked perfectly.  File outputs as expected and in less than 5 minutes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per [@Alan Schofield](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1775389/alan-schofield) in the comments, placing the map in a subreport and placing the subreport in the tablix resolves the issue.